# scikit-learn: Why does this 2-fold cross-validation figure looks like 4-fold cross-validation?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

The [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#k-fold) uses this figure to illustrate 2-fold cross-validation

[image]

It is obvious that the testing set accounts for 1/4, although the code is `n_splits=2`

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

>>> X = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
>>> kf = KFold(n_splits=2)
>>> for train, test in kf.split(X):
...     print("%s %s" % (train, test))
[2 3] [0 1]
[0 1] [2 3]
```

Why does the figure looks like 4-fold cross-validation? Is it a mismatched figure?

Comment: If you click on the picture you can see that it comes from the code for 4-fold validation https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_cv_indices.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The picture is coming from a 4-cross validation, you are right. Based on your code snippet , you have a two-fold split.

It looks similiar like the documentaiton of Kfold:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
>>> X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> kf = KFold(n_splits=2)
>>> kf.get_n_splits(X)
2
>>> print(kf)  
KFold(n_splits=2, random_state=None, shuffle=False)
>>> for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
...    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
...    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
...    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
TRAIN: [2 3] TEST: [0 1]
TRAIN: [0 1] TEST: [2 3]
```